# How does one calculate the theoretical, initial density of radioistope when one does not have a sample?

Tags: nuclear-physics

How can you calculate theoretical density of a radioistope? I've been struggling to find a solution because

1. The radioistope I'm researching has no data about it's density. It only has the atomic mass/weight.

   2. Don't you need *at least* two atoms to calculate the density, classically at least?

Am I missing something? Is the density of a isotope the same as it's "parent" on the periodic table?

Answer (score 1):

The isotope of an element doesn't [noticeably] affect the packing density of the atoms: that packing density is entirely determined by the electrons and nuclear charge, which is the same from isotope to isotope. So, for a given element, the density is directly proportional to atomic mass.

For instance, if $K^{30}$ had a density of 5g/cm^3, and an atomic mass of 50amu; and $K^{31}$ has an atomic mass of 51.2amu; then the density of $K^{31}$ is (5g/cm^3)*(51.2amu)/(50amu) = 5.12 g/cm^3.

[Numbers totally fictional!]